# MirrorLink Emulator

Tags: emulation, simulator, mirrorlink

I'm planning to develop an app which should have MirrorLink support. To see how it looks like during development I'd like to see it on an emulator.

The question is : Is there any MirrorLink Emulator available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An account for [CCC](https://carconnectivity.org/) is needed (you have to wait for like 2h before they confirm your account) in order to access dev documents.

I've uploaded the [emulator](https://www.mediafire.com/file/3g66r1uns9h64xz/MlClient-2.0.0-bin-2019-06-28.tar.gz/file) and his [pdf](https://www.mediafire.com/file/011rvz0twmw6xbi/QtMlClient_UserManual_ML13_2019-06-06.pdf/file) to save time.

First you need Ubuntu 16.04 or later. Then you need qt5.
Make sure you have the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libqca-qt5-2-dev libxmlsec1-dev xmlsec1 libusb-1.0
```

And also multimedia lib is required in order to meet the ALSA lib requirement:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qtmultimedia5-dev
```